# Transfer file to Tomcat location

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, file-upload

I'm trying to implement file upload functionality in a Spring application.

Currently, I am using the `multiple` attribute of HTML5 forms to send multiple files to the server.  The files are htting the controller, but I am having issues transferring them to the server destination.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleUpload(@RequestParam("files[]") List<MultipartFile> files, Model model) {

    String fileName;
    File transferFile;
    String filePath = System.getProperty("catalina.base") + File.separator + "resources" + File.separator;
    ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>(files.size());
    ArrayList<String> fileNameList = new ArrayList<String>(files.size());


    for (MultipartFile file : files) {

        fileName = filePath + file.getOriginalFilename();
        transferFile = new File(fileName);
        fileNameList.add(fileName);

        try {
            if (transferFile.exists()) {
                logger.info("Successful Transfer!");
                file.transferTo(transferFile);
            else 
                logger.info("Could not create file at " + fileName);
```

I left out the catch blocks and other logging but the `transferFile` object is created but it does not exist at the location.

How can I create the file at the specified location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. check you added  enctype='multipart/form-data' in form tag.

Check you define in configuration file spring.xml

> ```
>  <beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
>  <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
>           <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000" />
>  </beans:bean>
> ```

2.check the name atribute of your file tag and use same in your controller method handleUpload.

3.Check whether the file is created or not at specified location by you in which you are transfering file from user i.e. check transferFile creates file or not at destination.

Comment: All 3 have been done.  Regarding second point, when stepping through the debugger, I can see the `files[]` list as a LinkedList, and the filenames are there.

Comment: transferFile = new File(fileName); Add    transferFile.createNewFile()  so it solve your problem.As you did not created new file so your transferFile.exists() condition is failed here.Now it will run perfectly.

Comment: That was the solution!  Thanks!